# Adding Parameter causing issues-No data displayed

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi all I  have a stored procedure with two parameters @Startdate and @Enddate. When i execute the procedure i get data.

Now i added a parameter and it has list of values. So i added a split function and added in the `WHERE` clause. Now after making the changes when i execute my SP i do not get any data. I tried commenting out the 3rd Parameter from the WHERE clause and now i see the data again. Not sure what is happening. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I have tried different split functions and `Charindex(','+cast(tableid as varchar(8000))+',', @Ids) > 0` and nothing has worked.
Thanks

Comment: you need to post your code. The error seems to be in either what your function is doing (check this first, the results of it) or how you are limiting it.  I'd look into one of these really fast split functions: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Is the output of the split function string type? If so, check if the returned value is a or 'a'.

Comment: yes the op is string type. I simply dont understand how adding a third parameter is causing issues. The to an ffrom date are doing great, but when i add a parameter with list of values  and use it in the where clause its messing up the out put. i just cant understand whats happening

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  The concatenation and splitting of parameter values is a poor design for performance reasons and, most importantly, very susceptible to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks.  Please research some alternatives.  If you must proceed down this path...

There are a great many split functions out there, but I used this one [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/) to illustrate a possible solution.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END
RETURN
END
GO
```

It's unclear, from your question, if you need to filter your results based on an int, varchar or various other data types available, but here are two options (and probably the most common).

```
DECLARE @TableOfData TABLE
    (
        ID_INT INT,
        ID_VAR VARCHAR(100),
        START_DATE DATETIME,
        END_DATE DATETIME
    )

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1)
SET @Delimiter = ','

SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HH, 1, GETDATE())
SET @Ids = '1,2,4'

--Create some test data
INSERT INTO @TableOfData
    SELECT 1, '1', GETDATE(), DATEADD(MI, 1, GETDATE())  --In our window of expected results (date + id)
    UNION SELECT 2, '2', GETDATE(), DATEADD(D, 1, GETDATE())  --NOT in our window of expected results b/c of date
    UNION SELECT 3, '3', GETDATE(), DATEADD(MI,2, GETDATE())  --NOT in our expected results (id)
    UNION SELECT 4, '4', GETDATE(), DATEADD(MI,4, GETDATE())  --In our window of expected results (date + id)

--If querying by string, expect 2 results
SELECT TD.* 
    FROM @TableOfData TD
        INNER JOIN dbo.fnSplitString(@Ids, @Delimiter) SS 
            ON TD.ID_VAR = SS.splitdata  
    WHERE START_DATE >= @StartDate
    AND END_DATE <= @EndDate

--If querying by int, expect 2 results
SELECT TD.* 
    FROM @TableOfData TD
        INNER JOIN dbo.fnSplitString(@Ids, @Delimiter) SS 
            ON TD.ID_INT = CONVERT(int, SS.splitdata)  
    WHERE START_DATE >= @StartDate
    AND END_DATE <= @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks sql am getting "invalid columnnmae "splitdata" error

Comment: Please share your parameters and spltidata function, I may be able to help with that info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter with a list directly in your query filter. Try storing that separated data into a table variable or temp table and call that in your query or use dynamic SQL to write your query if you don't want to use table variable or temp tables.

Comment: The OP stated they are splitting the multi value parameter